# Scrollview Subviews always 2

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am coming across a strange error. Whenever I call a `scrollviews subviews`, it always has a count of two, or returns an array of two depending on what I am using.

I have a `scrollview` with about **20 subviews**. I am using the following code to try and retrieve the amount of `subviews` in that `scrollview`:

```
int svCount = svContent.Subviews.Length
```

Which always returns 2 no matter if I add a new scrollview or try use my existing one. The other code I am trying is as follows:

```
UIView[] viewArr = svContent.Subviews
```

Which also returns an array of two subviews. If I try and remove any of those subviews usign RemoveFromSuperview() it does nothing. I tried using the count on my base view as well which also in turn returns 2.

I am using `XCode 9.1` and `Visual Studio 2017` on `Windows 10 x64`.
Anyone have a clue about this ? Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: 1. Check if your scrollView contains 2 subviews, that other 20 sub subviews are included in the  scrollView.subviews. 2. Where did you put the debug code , after all the subviews are added ?

Comment: @Cole Xia, those two subviews contain no child subviews. And I tried the debug code on ViewDidLoad,  viewDidLayoutSubviews, and viewWillAppear, none of them returned the right amount. All returned 2 and those 2 have no subviews.